# CREATE VIEW must be the only statement in the batch / Export-DbaScript - DBATools

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, scripting, dbatools

I know that the solution is add a '`GO`' statement at the begin of the code but the fact is, the final objective is a PowerShell script in order to automate the creation of all objects of a database and then start a new database creation in other server with other different version and then migrate all the data to the new server and DB.

The problem is when I use the command (`Export-DbaScript`)  to export the SMO script creation and when I use the command '`Invoke-DbaQuery`' in order to create for example a stored procedure or view then failed with this message:

`CREATE VIEW` must be the only statement in the batch

Here part of my code:

```
$Options = New-DbaScriptingOption
$Options.AppendToFile= $False
$Options.AllowSystemObjects= $False
$Options.ClusteredIndexes= $True
$Options.DriAll= $True
$Options.ScriptDrops= $False
$Options.IncludeHeaders=$False
$Options.ToFileOnly=$True
$Options.Indexes = $True
$Options.Permissions=$True
$Options.WithDependencies=$False

Get-DbaDbView -SqlInstance Myserver -Database MyDatabase -View MyView | Export-DbaScript -ScriptingOptionsObject $Options  -Path  MyPath.SQL

Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance Myserver -Database MyDatabase -File MyPath.SQL
```

The problem is with the two first statements (`SET ANSI_NULLS ON` and `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`)

Is any option with the command 'Export-DbaScript' to avoid those commands or at least add 'GO'statement right after the command?

I prefer avoid manual fix due to one of the objectives is a dynamically script with very few manual contact from IT

Example output

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON         -- see the note below 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[viewtest]
AS
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tabletest]
```

**Note**: Putting the '`GO`' statement after the `SET` commands above solves the problem but it is a manual fix, I can not do that in the hundreds of automated scripts I generate.

Comment: Set [`$Options.BatchSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.batchsize?view=sql-smo-160#microsoft-sqlserver-management-smo-scriptingoptions-batchsize)?

Comment: I think you're looking for the `ScriptBatchTerminator` property on your ScriptingOptions object. On my machine, it defaults to false; try setting it to true and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @BenThul I was able to add the 'GO' statement in all script, the bad news are that option is creating a lot of empty spaces between letters. 

example
``` 
S E T   A N S I _ N U L L S   O N
G O
S E T   Q U O T E D _ I D E N T I F I E R   O N 
G O 

C R E A T E   V I E W   [ d b o ] . [ v i e w t e s t ]
A S
S E L E C T   *   F R O M   [ d b o ] . [ t a b l e t e s t ] 

```

Comment: What editor did you use to open the resulting file? I as because I've seen that behavior from notepad not correctly handling the file being UTF-16 encoded.